# Z-index issues in IE8 while using 960 grid

Tags: internet-explorer-8, z-index, 960.gs

I am having an issue in IE8 where my dropdown-style navigation is going behind another element. I have tried everything from setting the offending element's zindex to 1 and the dropdown to 99 and 999. I think it has something to do with the fact that I'm using 960 grid, as it worked before when I wasn't.

Update: Problem occurs in IE8.0.6 but not IE8.0.7

Update 2: Problem occurs in IE8.0.6001.187021C but not IE8.0.6001.1870

I hate Microsoft.

[Here is my stylesheet](http://martinmoto.com/static/css/style.css) and you can see the issue happening [here](http://martinmoto.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue also appears in IE 7.0.6002.18005, I don't have 8 but the following seems to work on for me locally and looks like it doesn't break Firefox so maybe it would work for IE8 as well but then again I don't know if its feasible for you or if it will cause you problems in future updates but its worth a shot:

In the main page I replaced in a few tags :

a) `<div id="left_container" class="grid_1">`

with
    `<div id="left_container" class="grid_1" style="position:static;">`

b) all occurnces of `<li class="last">` 
with `<li class="last" style="position:static;">`

OR

Find/replace following class & selector in external CSS as follows:

**960grid.css**

```
.container_5 .grid_1 {
    WIDTH: 182px;
      position:static;
}
```

**style.css**

```
#drop_nav .last {
    BORDER-BOTTOM: #fff 0px solid;
      position:static;
}
```

`Btw` I just tried it on IE8 6001 18720 & there was no issues at all with your web page. I didn't have to change anything & it displayed ok (didn't edit the css or anything just visitied the url and it worked).

Comment: Issues as in it wasn't having the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

IE is known to have z-index bugs, this has nothing to do with 960 grid.

You can either give the list container (#left_container) a higher z-index:

```
#left_container {
    z-index: 999;
}
```

or lower the z-index for the center_element:

```
#center_element {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

see also: http://doctype.com/ie8-zindex-anomaly

Comment: As I stated, the center element is currently 999 or something like that, and the center element is 1. Does -1 have a different effect?

Comment: Specifically having problems with IE8.0.6001.187021C, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Try to also give "#drop_nav li" a z-index